# How to design data provider

Tags: python, design-patterns, data-manipulation

I have an application made of many individual scripts. Output of each of them is an input od the next one. Each script reads data on the beggining and saves modified data as its last activity. In short:

- script1.py: reads mariadb data to df -> does stuff -> saves raw data in mysql.sql sqlite3 format
- script2.py: reads sqlite3 file -> does stuff -> saves raw data in data.txt - tab separated values
- program3.exe: reads data.txt -> does stuff -> writes another.txt - tab separated values
- script4.py: reads another.txt -> does stuff -> creates data4.csv
- script5.py: reads data4.csv -> does stuff -> inserts mariadb entries

What I am searching and asking for is: is there any design pattern (or other mechanism) for creating data provider for situation like that? "Data provider" should be a some abstraction layer which:

- have different data source types (like mariadb connection, csv files, txt files, others) predefined and easy to extern that list.
- should reads data from "data-specified-source" and deliver the data to given script/proggram (f.i. by execute script with parameter)
- should validate if output of each application part (each script/program) is valid or take over the task of generating this data

In general "Data provider" would run script1.py with some parameter (dataframe?) in some sandbox, take over data before it is saved and prepare data for script2.py proper execution. OR it just could run script1.py with some parameter, wait for execution, check if output is valid, convert (if necessary) that output to another format and run script2.py with well-prepared data.

I have access to python script sources (script1.py ... script5.py) and I can modify them. I am unable to modify program3.exe source code but it is always one part of the whole process. What is the best way (or just a way) to design such a layer?

Comment: Check out the Pipes and Filters pattern

Answer (score 0):

Since you include a .exe file, I'll assume you are using Windows. You can write a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) or a [powershell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell). On linux the equivalent would be a bash script.

If your sources and destinations are hard coded, then the batch file is going to be something like

```
script1.py 
REM assume output file is named mysql.sql
script2.py
REM assume output file is data.txt and has tab separated values
program3.exe
REM assume output file is another.txt and has tab separated values
script4.py
REM creates data4.csv
script5.py
```

The `REM` is short for REMARK in a batch file and allows for commenting.

Comment: Thank you but it should be more general. We have many projects with similar pattern and I'm searching one solution for every project which could be a part of documentation also. Some parsers are required.

Comment: What do you mean by "parsers are required"? What would it mean to be more general? Your question provides only one workflow, so it's challenging to identify what would constitute a pattern.

Comment: I mean that output of script1.py can be different (different separator in csv file for example) than required input in script2.py. In hardest situation script1.py could put something into mariadb database and script2.py needs that data in input.data sqlite3 file without one of columns. So a data provider should has access to all "outputs" and deliver data as entry data to the next scripts in required way.

Comment: More general means also that I would like use it in many projects with similar (list of scripts) structure. So if there was any similar part (like changing seperator to destination script) in other project - the data provider would already know how to deal with it.

Comment: Do you already have a collection of workflows, or are you anticipating constructing them? If you already have examples, then identifying patterns and abstractions is the best way to proceed. If you are merely anticipating potential complexity, then I can't provide specific insight.